# The captured image from camera is not storing in full size

Tags: android, image, camera, sd-card

I know this question has been asked so many times in this forum. But still I couldn't get the solution.
Basically in my application, I am calling an inbuilt camera intent, capturing image and displaying a bitmap in imageview and storing it in sd card. Now the image what i get in my folder is of small size like a thumbnail.

My code is

```
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, "Select picture"), CAMERA_REQUEST);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          try {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            if (photo != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }

            // Image name

            final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            final String[] p1 = new String[] {  MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, 
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN };
            Cursor c1 = cr.query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null,
                    null, p1[1] + " DESC");
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/"  + c1.getInt(0);
                Uri newuri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);

                String snapName = getRealPathFromURI(newuri);

                Uri u = Uri.parse(snapName);

                File f = new File("" + u);
                String fileName = f.getName();

                editTextPhoto.setText(fileName);
                checkSelectedItem = true;

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /* ignored for PNG */, bos);
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

                // Storing Image in new folder
                StoreByteImage(mContext, bitmapdata, 100, fileName);

                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

                // Delete the image from the Gallery

                getContentResolver().delete(newuri, null, null);

            }
            c1.close();

            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in creating Image." + e);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in creating Image." + e);
        }
        System.out.println("*** End of onActivityResult() ***");
    }

        public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }

        public boolean StoreByteImage(Context pContext, byte[] pImageData,
                int pQuality, String pExpName) {

            String nameFile = pExpName;
            // File mediaFile = null;
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/pix/images");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
            try {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 0;
                Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pImageData, 0,
                        pImageData.length, options);
                if (!sdImageMainDirectory.exists()) {
                    sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
                }

                sdImageMainDirectory = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, nameFile);
                sdImageMainDirectory.createNewFile();

                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        sdImageMainDirectory.toString());
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        fileOutputStream);
                myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, pQuality, bos);

                bos.flush();
                bos.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(pContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(pContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and ImageView in main.xml is

```
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:src="@drawable/gray_pic"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        />
```

With this code i get an Imageview and the image stores in my folder with small size.
If I add intent.putExtra then neither image captured displays in ImageView nor image creates in new folder.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
path += "/myFolder/myPicture.jpg";
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
cameraIntent.putExtra("output", outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(cameraIntent, "Select Picture"), CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
```

Don't know where I am struck..
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Camera intent as:

```
 Intent photoPickerIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,  getTempFile());
                   photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                   photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent,"Select Picture"),TAKE_PICTURE);
```

//getTempFile()

```
 private Uri getTempFile() {
    //         if (isSDCARDMounted()) {

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Equip");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            Log.d("filename",filename);
            File file = new File(root,filename+".jpeg" );

                   muri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                   photopath=muri.getPath();
                   Item1.photopaths=muri.getPath();

          Log.e("getpath",muri.getPath());
               return muri;
    //         } else {
    //         return null;
               }
              //}
           private boolean isSDCARDMounted(){
               String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
               if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
               return true;
               else
               return false;

               }
```

And Check in your Folder, click on thumbnail it will show actual image

Comment: Thanks Abhi for the reply. But still I am getting the same result. The folder itself is not creating. Does my outputFileUri is correct in the above code? And also not getting image thumbnail in the imageview... Actually I am using StoreByteImage() method to create folder and store image. Any changes in that method to be done?

Comment: Checked with the edited code. But still the image getting in my folder is of very small size. When I capture the image, the size of image in gallery is around 1200KB while its size in my folder is around 19kb..

Comment: you have to click on thumb nail to see the original image in SD card

Comment: I did that and downloaded it to my computer also. Its coming as thumb nail only.